# list() returns no files when fetching from a folder in a Supabase storage bucket

Tags: flutter, supabase

I'm new to flutter and supabase. I am trying to list all files in a specific folder in a bucket.

In this example, namely folder '1'.

```
Future<List<FileObject>> fetchFilesFromFolder() async {
    return await supabase
    .storage
    .from('public-images')
    .list(path: folderId.toString()); // folderId is '1'
  }

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final objects = fetchFilesFromFolder();
    
    return FutureBuilder<List<FileObject>>(
            future: objects,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                final files = snapshot.data!;
                print('FOLDER ID');
                print(folderId);
                print('Fetched objects:');
                print(files);
...
```

The line print(files) prints out an empty list.
Why is it not fetching the files?

I'd like to point us that getPublicUrl() works fine in the project, so I assume the Supabase set up should be fine?

```
final url1 = supabase.storage
                  .from('public-images')
                  .getPublicUrl('1/hackney1.jpeg');
```

For context, this is the content of the storage:
[Content of my supabase bucket](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6kBWP.png)

I'd really appreciate the help. Thank you!

Comment: What output do you get if you do `print(objects) before the return statement?

Comment: @Rakozay it unfortunately just outputs `Instance of '_Future<List<FileObject>>’`..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.list()` requires `select` RLS policy on your bucket even if it's a public bucket.

```sql
create policy "Public Access"
on storage.objects for select
using ( bucket_id = 'public-images' );
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer–really appreciate it! It is now returning the corresponding objects in the list. :)